# How to use a server replacement on own computer with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a hobbyist and have been trying to write a useful program to use at my work that is stand alone and doesn't require to be run on a server. I'll skip all the in between details but I ended up using ASP.NET to write a bunch of it that I like but I ran into a problem: I do not have (nor want) a server to run it on. What I'd like is just an icon on my desktop that will run the pgm/website on my local machine.

After quite some searching I found [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20CassiniDev%20to%20host%20ASP.Net%20in%20your%20application&referringTitle=Documentation), which looks really good to me, but it is way over my head in terms of complexity. I don't know how to implement it and I can not find any documentation that I can understand. When attempting various things I just get error after error so I am obviously doing something wrong.

Is there anyone that can write what to do in an answer below? Even if it's just a direction to look in that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look on HttpListener

Comment: Why not use IIS on your local machine?

Comment: What does it need to do? You can write a html file that contains javascript that can do a lot of pretty things. Does it need to connect to a database? Does it need to read or write data? You don't necessarily need a server for that. Do you have existing code written that actually requires a server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I do want to use an SQL server but haven't put the code in yet since I want to first make sure I can get it working in the first place. How would I not use a server but still use ASP.NET?

Comment: Here is a guide to client side reading and writing of data  http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: If you want to use ASP.Net and SQL Server, you need to get over not wanting to use a server! Any particular reason? Too complicated? Use it as an opportunity to learn!

Comment: Looks like this one http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ is precompiled, so no code, compiling required.

Comment: Just to clarify, IIS doesn't need a 'server' to run on - just any old PC with an appropriate OS. But if you want 100's of users you might want to upgrade that PC to something more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply install `IIS` on your machine. You can install it by

1. Click Start
2. Click on control panel
3. Click on Programs
4. Click on Turn Windows features on or off
5. In the list of window feature check Internet Information Services(IIS)
6. Select extra bits and bobs from the dropdown if required otherwise click on Ok
7. Wait for it to install
8. Once install you will need to add your website.
9. Open IIS
10. Expand the treenode on the left hand menu
11. Right click on `Sites` folder and select `Add Site`
12. Give your site a name, physical path, port and your done
13. Make sure your the website root folder has the correct permissions in particular `IIS_IUSERS`

Installing IIS guide **[here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7)**

Add website to IIS guide **[here](http://www.iisunderground.com/add-a-new-website-iis-7-5/)**

Comment: Because sometimes you have a small product for simple end-users and you don't want to force them to install IIS in order to use it

Comment: In this case he wants to run it on his desktop. No deployment.

Comment: @Nissim The OP did not mention anything about end-users

Comment: @Izzy But he did say **I do not have (nor want) a server to run it on**

Comment: @Nissim You don't need a server to run IIS

Comment: Just to clarify, I mean running the pgm on a computer where it is used, so basically running on localhost or whatever works, but not on an external server

Comment: @LuukV Install `IIS` on your local machine and view the app on localhost

Answer (score 0):

CassiniDev is too complicated?! Are you serious?!
All you need is the following call:

```
var server = new CassiniDev.Server([port], [path to your published web application]);
server.Start();
```

And you're done!
You can now browse to:
http://localhost:[port] and voilà

Comment: That's kind of the thing, I'm sure people that know what they're talking about have no problem what so ever, but where do I put this code? Just in a separate class? Or somewhere in my web forms. All I've done is some YouTube and a lot of other documentation on ASP.NET but nothing on the use of servers.

Comment: The code I posted simply starts your server. put it wherever you think it's needed. If you want it when your winforms app loads - put it under the `Form_Load` event. if you want it when a button is clicke - put it in its `Click` event handler

Comment: I guess this code would for example need to compiled as a console app and run seperately. To be fair, coding, compiling, installing and running your own web server is probably more complicated than just ticking the IIS box. Just IMHO :)

Comment: I've been using CassiniDev as part of my application (windows service) for years. It's a great feature for when you want to supply ASP.NET web-access to your application without all the IIS hassle (I don't want to request the client to install new features). It's simple, friendly and tweakable (open-sourced).

Comment: Sounds ideal... if you have time the OP might need some more details though. Am I correct in saying this code does not go into his existing ASP.Net code (as it needs this to run inside of in the first place). It'd need to be something running in a separate process beforehand

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid When developing, i'm using IIS/IISExpress. When releasing - I publish the application and use CassiniDev to host it **inside my main process** and it does fantastic job!

Comment: So in this case (I could probably look it up) you deploy an application ad the first thing it does is spawn a Cassini web server and the second thing it does is runs your web app inside that server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Cassini is an assembly. your application actually hosts the web-server in-process

Comment: @Nissim Thanks for the reply, looks like you know exactly what I'm looking for. If you could make the time to expand your answer with bit more specifics that would be greatly appreciated. Kind of from the hand-holding point of view. Because it still isn't working for me (on a new project with one line of text on the actual web page) though I've been playing around for another day now. I tried just starting it from the executable file but this also gives me errors. Thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HttpListener, follow the below example:

https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx

Comment: This is an alternative method. Just let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't really have a clue how to use this together with, for example, a .NET website that I made. Do you have any info on that since I wasn't able to find it.